# Geoserver CSS min max scale

Tags: geoserver

I have layer with a lot of points being displayed.
It does not make sense to display these points until the zoom level is quite close.

How can I configure this layer to not show any points until a certain zoom level has been reached?

I am using geoserver 2.10 with the CSS extension installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a scale dependent rule as described in the [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/css/tutorial.html#scale-dependent-styles).

```
[@scale < 20000000] {
  label: [STATE_ABBR];
  label-anchor: 0.5 0.5;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-fill: black;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 14;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Think I had gotten to the point of not seeing woods for the trees been looking at various css tutorials all morning.